# Get the result of post json data to wcf rest service

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf

I have a rest service.

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/AddNews", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool Add(News entity);
```

Here the imp :

```
  public bool Add(News entity)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.News.Add(entity);
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I post  data to my service but i need the result of my operation that here is `bool` .how can i get the result in my code ?

```
   News student = new News
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Subject = "wfwf",
                ViewerCounter = 1, // removed the "" (string)
                MainContent = "fsdsd", // renamed from "Content"
                SubmitDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
                PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
                TypeOfNews = "adsadaad"
            };
            WebClient Proxy1 = new WebClient();
            Proxy1.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializerToUplaod = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(News));
            serializerToUplaod.WriteObject(ms, student);
             Proxy1.UploadData("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews", "POST", ms.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
byte[] a=    Proxy1.UploadData("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews", "POST", ms.ToArray());


            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a);
```